# Only allow certain fields (Firestore Rules)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Im trying to create a rule that only allows certain fields to be updated within my firestore rules, so I thought about doing a function like so:

```
function checkFieldsSent() {
        for(field in request.resource.data) {
          if (!(field in ['userRole', 'userName', 'messageType', 'userMessage', 'userHonourLevel', 'userAvatar', 'userChatPosted', 'userLevel', 'userChatMessage'])) { return false }
        }
        return true
      }
```

of course as you can imagine, firestore moans about the use of "FOR" and "Return" within that function.

Does anyone know a solution? So if the request comes through with fields that ARE NOT ALLOWED to be updated it disallows the update.

Kind Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are not allowed in the rules. But there is a new data type available since February that gives a nice solution: Map.Diff.

```
function checkFieldsSent() {
  let forbiddenfields = ['userRole', 'userName', 'messageType', 'userMessage', 'userHonourLevel', 'userAvatar', 'userChatPosted', 'userLevel', 'userChatMessage'];
  return !request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(forbiddenfields);
}
```

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#affectedKeys)